# QUdpSocket loses validity

Tags: c++, qt, udp, signals-slots, qudpsocket

I've a question regarding QUdpSocket:
I'm receiving UDP messages on port `50011` to multicast address `239.0.0.1` about every 0.2 seconds (Proven by wireshark).

The following code is working well (and printing "VALID" on every message) for ~ 1 minute. After that `messageHandler` is not being called by the `QUdpSocket's` signal `readyRead` anymore (even though I've double checked with wireshark, and messages are still being send).

```
ServiceDiscovery::ServiceDiscovery(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    socket(new QUdpSocket(this))
{
    socket->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 50011, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
    socket->joinMulticastGroup(QHostAddress("239.0.0.1"));
    connect(socket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, 
            this, &ServiceDiscovery::messageHandler, 
            Qt::DirectConnection);
}

void ServiceDiscovery::messageHandler()
{
    if(socket->isOpen()) qDebug("OPEN"); // Does not print, ofc.
    if(socket->isReadable()) qDebug("READABLE"); // Does not print.
    if(socket->isValid()) qDebug("VALID"); // Suddenly stops.

    QByteArray datagram;
    while(socket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
        Message response(datagram);
        if(response.deserialize()) {
            if(response.getServiceID() == constants::servicediscovery::SERVICE_ID) {
                QByteArray payload = response.getPayload();
                if(payload.size() >= 48) {
                    QString address = QHostAddress(payload.mid(32, 4).toHex().toUInt(nullptr, 16)).toString();
                    quint16 port = payload.mid(38, 2).toHex().toUInt(nullptr, 16);
                    emit found(address, port);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Due to comments I pasted the datagram handling, too.

Comment: What if you comment out code that process the datagrams? It might be that your system is not able to process so many requests (at least 5 per second), or deadlocked.

Comment: @vahancho I updated the code. ´response.deserialize()´ is forming a QString from the datagram.

Comment: Sorry, by "comment out" I meant just removing that code and do not process datagrams at all. This will make things run faster. If it works faster it will handle more messages. If you will see that "VALID" message still printed, this will be an indication that your datagram processing code is not able to process that many pending datagrams and just blocks the event loop.

Comment: I can't comment it out, since my application is dependant on that. But deadlock is a good guess. Simply making the handler re-entrant won't fix my problem tho, when there's a performance issue that causes it...

Answer (score 0):

For the Records:
I had the same problem. The reason: A demo library my Application is relying on closes after the evaluation time not only its open ports but all ports of the application.